# Git add files to repo with files in it already

Tags: git, github

How do I add a folder to my Github repository that already has a folder in it.
I have been trying to do it but git comes with different kinds of errors. Can someone guide me through it?

Thanks

Comment: See [ask] - when something "comes with ... errors", we need to see (1) what you did and (2) what the error result was. (It's also helpful if you say what you expected, in many cases, although here that seems less-likely to be helpful.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUGGESTION:

1. If you haven't already done so, "git clone" your GitHub remote repository to your local hard drive.
2. In your local repository, you can add files and directories at will.
3. Once you're ready, you can "git add ." and "git commit -m ...".
4. And once you're done, you can "git push" back to GitHub

Comment: Thank you so much. i got it running on no time.

Comment: Now I have a double blue folder icon I cannot click on

Comment: Please make a different question about that. Also you might want to learn some [git "advanced" basics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3m7BgIvC-uQ)